Wrap buffer in miniz tinfl_decompress
I am trying to use MINIZ library in my embedded device, and am almost done with success except for an issue in decompressing, similar to the one reported here:
Wrap buffer in minizs tinfl_decompress
Basically, my code will only work fine as long as the size of decompressed data is smaller than the given output buffer, otherwise I get corrupted bytes: I know I should handle TINFL_STATUS_HAS_MORE_OUTPUT return code, but even after trying several ways, and searching for examples, that behaviour never changes.
This is my code:
  int i=0;
  tinfl_decompressor decomp;
  tinfl_status status;
  uint8_t ibuf[256],obuf[TINFL_LZ_DICT_SIZE];
  size_t src_buf_len,out_buf_len;
  int out_buf_ofs;
  
  *crc=0xffffffff;
  *len=0;

  tinfl_init(&decomp);
  out_buf_ofs=0;
  src_buf_len=sizeof(ibuf);
  do {
    src_buf_len=SuperFileRead(f1,ibuf,min(totbytes,sizeof(ibuf)));
    out_buf_len=TINFL_LZ_DICT_SIZE-out_buf_ofs;
    status = tinfl_decompress(&decomp,ibuf,&src_buf_len,
      obuf, ((uint8_t*)obuf)+out_buf_ofs, &out_buf_len, 
      /*flags |*/ (totbytes>0 ? TINFL_FLAG_HAS_MORE_INPUT : 0));

    totbytes-=src_buf_len;
    if(status != TINFL_STATUS_DONE)
      SuperFileSeek(f1,src_buf_len-sizeof(ibuf),SEEK_CUR);  // occhio alla fine...
//ovvero    SuperFileSeek(f1,  ,SEEK_SET);

    if(out_buf_len) {
      if(SuperFileWrite(f2,((uint8_t*)obuf)+out_buf_ofs,out_buf_len) != out_buf_len)
        break;
      *len+=out_buf_len;
      }
    
    *crc=crc32array(((uint8_t*)obuf)+out_buf_ofs,out_buf_len,*crc);
    out_buf_ofs = (out_buf_ofs+out_buf_len) & (TINFL_LZ_DICT_SIZE-1);
    
    if(!totbytes)  // safety cmq
      break;
    } while(status==TINFL_STATUS_NEEDS_MORE_INPUT || status == TINFL_STATUS_HAS_MORE_OUTPUT);
  
  *crc=~Reflect32(*crc);


(tried different output size and still get the same)
I've been reading and studying example code, and trying different buffer sizes (and small changes in pointer management, and configuration parameters/constants), but the above error is consistent and never changes
The post I am referring to says "the issue was solved" but does not show exactly how.
Is there some mistake I am still running into?
thanks
